# golang *IPConn.Read(b []byte) Blocked and unable to read data

Tags: ipv4

golang *IPConn.Read(b []byte) Blocked and unable to read data

How should I receive response packets

```golang
tcp := TcpHeader{
        SrcPort:    61450,
        DstPort:    80,
        Seq:        1135293281,
        DataOffset: 20,
        SYN:        true,
        Window:     65535,
    }
    tcp.Checksum = CheckSum(tcp, srcip, dstip)

    laddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip4:tcp", "192.168.0.203")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    raddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip4:tcp", "192.168.0.198")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    conn, err := net.DialIP("ip4:tcp", laddr, raddr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    _, err = conn.Write(tcp.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    p := make([]byte, 64)
    _, err = conn.Read(p)
    return err
```

[wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjE03.png)

```golang
p := make([]byte, 64)
_, err := conn.Read(p)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I would like to receive response data